# Why there is no std::future::try_wait()?

Tags: c++, c++11, currency, future, producer-consumer

Given that there are `std::future::wait_for/until()`, I don't see why there is no `std::future::try_wait()`. I'm currently writing a producer-consumer example, and I want to use `std::future` as a convenient way to signal the consumer threads to return. My consumer code is like

```
void consume(std::future<void>& stop) {
  while (!stop.try_wait()) { // alas, no such method
    // try consuming an item in queue
  }
}
```

I'm thinking to simulate `try_wait()` with a zero-duration `wait_for()` which is really ugly. As a side question: any other convenient ways to signal the consumer threads to return?

Comment: Just use a `std::atomic<bool>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::experimental::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/future) has a `.is_ready()` and `.then( F )` methods added to it.

`is_ready` is probably your `try_wait` (without a timeout).

`wait_for`, as noted, gives you the functionality of `try_wait` in practice.

---

`std::future` is not designed as a signaling mechanism even if it can be used as one.  If you want a signaling mechansim, create one using a condition variable, mutex, and state that stores the state of the signals (possibly combining them).

```
struct state {
  bool stop = false;
  unsigned some_value = 7;
  friend auto as_tie( state const& s ) {
    return std::tie(s.stop, s.some_value);
  }
  friend bool operator==( state const& lhs, state const& rhs ) {
    return as_tie(lhs)==as_tie(rhs);
  }
};

template<class State, class Cmp=std::equal<State>>
struct condition_state {
  // gets a copy of the current state:
  State get_state() const {
    auto l = lock();
    return state;
  }
  // Returns a state that is different than in:
  State next_state(State const& in) const {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return !Cmp{}(in, state); } );
    return state;
  }
  // runs f on the state if it changes from old.
  // does this atomically in a mutex, so be careful.
  template<class F>
  auto consume_state( F&& f, State old ) const {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return !Cmp{}(old, state); } );
    return std::forward<F>(f)( state );
  }
  // runs f on the state if it changes:
  template<class F>
  auto consume_state( F&& f ) const {
    return consume_state( std::forward<F>(f), state );
  }
  // calls f on the state, then notifies everyone to check if
  // it has changed:
  template<class F>
  void change_state( F&& f ) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      std::forward<F>(f)( state );
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  // Sets the value of state to in
  void set_state( State in ) {
    change_state( [&](State& state) {
      state = std::move(in);
    } );
  }
private:
  auto lock() const { return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m); }
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  State state;
};
```

For an example, suppose our `State` was a vector of ready tasks and a bool saying "abort":

```
struct tasks_todo {
  std::deque< std::function<void()> > todo;
  bool abort = false;
  friend bool operator==()( tasks_todo const& lhs, tasks_todo const& rhs ) {
    if (lhs.abort != rhs.abort) return false;
    if (lhs.todo.size() != rhs.todo.size()) return false;
    return true;
  }
};
```

then we can write our queue as follows:

```
struct task_queue {
  void add_task( std::function<void()> task ) {
    tasks.change_state( [&](auto& tasks) { tasks.todo.push_back(std::move(task)); } );
  }
  void shutdown() {
    tasks.change_state( [&](auto& tasks) { tasks.abort = true; } );
  }
  std::function<void()> pop_task() {
    return tasks.consume_state(
      [&](auto& tasks)->std::function<void()> {
        if (tasks.abort) return {};
        if (tasks.todo.empty()) return {}; // should be impossible
        auto r = tasks.front();
        tasks.pop_front();
        return r;
      },
      {} // non-aborted empty queue
    );
  }
private:
  condition_state<task_todo> tasks;
};
```

or somesuch.

Comment: If I just need a one-off event (no need for reset), `future` looks quite convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Since std::future::wait_for is not available, one can specify own timeout routine as shown in the snippet:

```
void even(int n,promise<bool> p)
{
   this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500ms)); //set milliseconds(10ms) to display result
   p.set_value( n%2 == 0?true:false);
}


int main()

{
    promise<bool> p;
    future<bool> f =p.get_future();
    int n = 100;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp1 = std::chrono::system_clock::now() ;
    thread t([&](){ even(n,move(p)); });      

    auto span = std::chrono::milliseconds(200ms);

    std::future_status s;

    do
    {
        s =f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0));
        // do something
    }
    while(  std::chrono::system_clock::now() < (tp1 + span) );


    if( s==future_status::ready)
        std::cout << "result is " << (f.get()? "Even": "Odd")  << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "timeout " << '\n';

    t.join();         
}
```

Comment: Why `thread* t = new thread ...` and not just `thread t([&](){ even(n,move(p)); });`? Or even simpler `future<bool> f = std::async(even, n)`

Comment: Doesn't answer the question of why `try_wait` is not provided